# Save/Load full form

Tags: vb.net, save, load

I am writing a program for a friend in my free time to use to document students for physical therapy and occupational therapy. I'm using visual basic and have created a basic form so far, but realized I'm not sure how to save/load the information that will be input.

This is what the form looks like so far (basic I know)
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWjWr.png)

I do not have access to sql or ms access at the moment so I'm hoping to be able to save all the information to a txt document or xml file and be able to read and update it at a future time. Eventually I will have multiple forms all associated with one student and would like to save them all together.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Depending on how the data is stored in the app, serialization might be an option or SQLite.  hard to say with something so broad and vague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method, it will work perfect but the data will be stored in a `xml` file and it's editable :

**First you go to your project properties :**

[image]

**Then you go the the settings tab :**

[image]

**And there you add all the variables that you need to store data in :**

[image]

**So to save the data you can use the `Form_Closing` event :**

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
   My.Settings.StudentName = StudentNameTextBox.Text
   '.......
   '....
   'And you do that for all the information that you need to store.
End Sub
```

**To Load the data when the form loads, just revers the storing way :**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     StudentNameTextBox.Text = My.Settings.StudentName
   '.......
   '....
   'And you do that for all the information that you need to load.
End Sub
```

**Hope that will be useful to you :)**

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @WillLeClerc , You're welcome :), please accept the answer if it was useful to so it can also help others.